# Losing Hotkey's using eclipse on UBUNTU

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys

When i am developing, sometimes eclipse lose all the hotkeys and i need click in "project explorer" and click again in tab of code, hotkeys return after this.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Eclipse: Luna Release 1 (4.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

The hotkeys are associated with commands in eclipse and these are context sensitive meaning the same short cut key can be used for the different handlers, depending on the context the specific handler will be executed.

Example: In the image below <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> is used for two commands. If you are editing a text then press this shortcut key ruler context menu will be shown. If editor is not active but view is active then view menu will be shown.

But you said

> sometimes eclipse lose **all** the hotkeys

This doesn't happens. Mention which hot key(s) are not working. Also you can check the context for these keys in **keys** preference page as shown in the image below(In **When** column)
[image]